# Android System.getenv weirdness

Tags: android, environment-variables

Can anyone explain why the following two lines output different values to the log?

```
Log.v(TAG, "getenv(name) = [" + System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + "]");
Log.v(TAG, "getenv().get(name) = [" + System.getenv().get("SECONDARY_STORAGE") + "]");
```

With the first I see:

```
getenv(name) = [/storage/extSdCard]
```

With the second I see:

```
getenv().get(name) = [/storage/extSdCard:/storage/UsbDriveA:/storage/UsbDriveB:/storage/UsbDriveC:/storage/UsbDriveD:/storage/UsbDriveE:/storage/UsbDriveF]
```

Not a big deal. I'm just curious.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that `getenv(String)` is not implemented as a lookup on the `Map<String, String>` returned by `getenv()`. They route to different POSIX functions, near as I can tell from the Android source code.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. It seems odd that this particular variable is the only one that shows a different value between the two methods. I thought it may be because of the 'path' separators (:) but there are others that also have these and show no difference.